# Accessing 2D planes of a 3D matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have a 3D matrix of dimensions 25 (rows) x 320 (cols) x 235 (channels)

For each of the 25 rows, I want to extract the 2D slice (320 x 235) so that I have 25 2D matrices.

I am not sure how to do this in OpenCV.

I thought of transposing the 3D matrix so that I have 320 (rows) x 235 (cols) x 25 (channels) and then using split to get 25 matrices, but the transpose doesn't seem to work (MATLAB doesn't even allow transpose on multidimensional arrays)

I then tried reshape to no avail.

Is it possible to use NAryMatIterator? Or if there is any other way to carry out this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the row() function to get a new header for a given row, just call if on every row and store them.  It is an O(1) operation because no data is copied, beware that any changes you make will be reflected in the original matrix.  There may be a more elegant solution but I am not aware of it.  The rest depends on how you want to store your 25 matrices (in an array, vector, anything you want).  Mat documentation can be found [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) though it is not terribly well structured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using the row() function does solve my problem to some extent. I get 25 arrays of dimension 1x320, each having 235 channels. I then did a reshape on each to get 320x235 dimensioned matrices.

Comment: I have never done something like that before so I wasn't sure if you would need reshape.  Glad you figured it out.